# Show that if $A\neq B$ then $C^A\cap C^B=\emptyset$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

**Definition**

A set $R$ is a (binary) relation if any its element is a ordered pair, that is $z\in R$ if and only if there exist $x$ and $y$ such that $z=(x,y)$. In particular if $R$ is contained in the cartesian product of two set $A$ and $B$ we say that $R$ is a relation of between $A$ and $B$ and if $B$ is equal to $A$ we say that $R$ is a relation in $A$.

**Definition**

If $R$ is a relation we call domain of $R$ that set whose elements are a first coordinate of some pair of the relation, that is
$$
\text{dom}\,R:=\{x:\exists\,y\,\text{such that}\,(x,y)\in R\}
$$
and analogously the range of $R$ is that set whose elements are the second coordinate of the relation, that is
$$
\text{rank}\,R:=\{y:\exists\,x\,\text{such that}\,(x,y)\in R\}
$$

So it is possible to prove that the above two defined set exist using the $ZFC$'s formalism but this now has not matter so we proceed to give the following well know definition.

**Definition**

A function $f$ is a relation such that if $(x,y)$ and $(x,z)$ are such that $(x,y),(x,z)\in f$ then $y=z$.

**Definition**

Let $A$ and $B$ sets. So the set whose element are functions from $A$ to $B$ is denoted by the symbol $B^A$.

Again it is possible to prove that the above defined set exist using $ZFC$'s formalism but now this again has not matter.

So with the previous definitino I ask to prove that when is true that if $A$ and $B$ are two different set then the set $C^A$ and $C^B$ for any other set $C$ are disjoint. So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prove by contradiction. Suppose the contrary that $C^{A}\cap C^{B}\neq\emptyset$.
Choose $f\in C^{A}\cap C^{B}.$ Since $A\neq B$, there exists $x$
such that $x\in A\setminus B$ or $x\in B\setminus A$. Case 1: $x\in A\setminus B$.
Note that $f:A\rightarrow C$ is a function and $x\in A$, so there exists (uniquely)
$y\in C$ such that $(x,y)\in f$. On the other hand, that $f:B\rightarrow C$
is a function and $(x,y)\in f$ implies that $x\in\mbox{dom}(f)=B$.
This is a contradiction.

Case 2: $x\in B\setminus A$ can be treated similarly.

Answer (score 5):

If $f\in C^A\cap C^B$ then
$$ A=\operatorname{dom} f = B $$